# Cant find button using Test Library (React)

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, react-testing-library

I'm must be missing something quite obvious, I have a react app that has a left div with multiple buttons, each one of them with different texts. I want to check if every one of those buttons was rendered.So for instance to find one of the buttons (using the Testing Library) I'm doing the following:

```
screen.getByText("/channels/i", { selector: "button" })
```

I Also tried

```
screen.getByRole("button", { name: /channels/i })
```

But I always get the result

```
TestingLibraryElementError: Unable to find an accessible element with the role "button" and name `/channels/i`

    There are no accessible roles. But there might be some inaccessible roles. If you wish to access them, then set the `hidden` option to `true`. Learn more about this here: https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-queries#byrole
```

But as you can see it does exist

[image]

Like that I have probably another 10 buttons, so I don't get why it says that there are no accessible roles.

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: if my answer doesn't solve your issue, I probably need to see more code on the Button component. Could you create a sandbox?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In this particular case, it actually was a stupid mistake, I had my render() placed somewhat like this:

```
render(<App />)
describe("Navigation", () => {
        it("Navigation Test 1", () => {...
```

So basically because I'm using Testing Library before each iteration "it" would clean my App component making getByRole not able to find the nodes.

The moment I placed render() inside "it", all started working... Stupid mistake and with the code I provided it would be really hard to guess. Thanks anyway Doug.

Answer (score 29):

There are mainly 2 possibilities I see.

1. Not waiting for the button to appear.
   If your button is rendered after a certain thing has finished loading, you need to wait for it to appear on the screen. You can do that with a [findBy](https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-queries/#findby) query.

```js
await screen.findByRole('button', { name: 'Channels' });
```

2. If your button is somehow not accessible, hidden by CSS or by `aria-hidden="true"`, it won't be found by the `getByRole` query. You can verify this by passing the `hidden` prop. Note you should probably not be using `hidden` in most cases.

```js
screen.getByRole('button', { name: 'Channels', hidden: true });
```

---

### Useful links

- [byRole](https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-queries/#byrole)
- [findBy](https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-queries/#findby)

Comment: very useful. It helped me solving the issue I had

Answer (score 2):

This can also be caused by the name of the button being wrong. E.g.

```js
screen.getByRole('button', { name: 'Sumbit' })
```

Note the typo: `'Sumbit'` instead of `'Submit'`. In this case, you get this very misleading error message:

```
Unable to find role="button"
```

I just lost half an hour on a simple typo and a bad error message.

Comment: This also just happened to me. I meant to pass the name as a regex since I presume this looks for an exact match. (i.e. `{name: 'Submit'}` doesn't match a button called `Submit…` but `{name: /Submit/}` gives a better error with other roles RTL tried.)